# En Android Studio al configurar el hardware del Android Virtual Device (AVD) el selector de gráficos y el input de RAM aparecen deshabilitados

Tags: android

Al crear un nuevo dispositivo virtual en Android Studio, no me permite cambiar los gráficos ni la RAM.

[image: Android Virtual Device Configuration]

[image: Versión de Android Studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación indica que debes crear un nuevo perfil de hardware

> [**Crear un perfil de hardware**](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds?hl=es-419#createhp)
> El Administrador de dispositivos
> proporciona perfiles de hardware predefinidos para dispositivos
> comunes de modo que puedas agregarlos fácilmente a tus definiciones de
> AVD. Si debes definir un dispositivo diferente, puedes crear un perfil
> de hardware nuevo.

Para crear un perfil de hardware nuevo desde el comienzo:

- En la ventana `Select Hardware`, haz clic en `New Hardware Profile`.
- En la ventana `Configure Hardware Profile`, **modifica las propiedades de perfiles de hardware según sea necesario**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pero es más intuitivo que si ya tienes perfiles predeterminados, que al seleccionarlo puedas modificar los demás valores y que al guardarlo te diga que tienes que darle un nombre nuevo, que básicamente es lo más sensato.

Answer (score 0):

Si seleccionas una definición de hardware no te permite cambiar estos parámetros pero si pulsas en el botón "New Hardware Profile" si. Gracias por hacerme perder el tiempo Google.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]